# Spring Data Couchbase findAll speed

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I added around 900 document to couchbase of two types (`Country and Rate`) and then trying to retrieve one type Country by extending `CrudRepository` and using `findAll`

```
public interface CountryRepository extends CrudRepository<Country, String> {

}
```

.

```
public interface RateRepository extends CrudRepository<Rate, String> {


    List<Rate> findByTopTrue();

    List<Rate> findByCountryStartingWith(String country);

    List<Rate> findByCountryIsoCode(String isoCode);

}
```

I created the view all as requested but the result is taking around 10 second , is this normal , note that when I use other methods in RateRepository they are super fast .

I did create also primary index and GSI for top field in Rate .

How can I check if the speed issue is related to couchbase or spring-data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out why view is that slow so i went to N1QL and it is much more faster i change the repostiory to be like below

```
public interface CountryRepository extends CrudRepository<Country, String> {
    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter}")
    List<Country> findAllCountries();
}
```

and used `findAllCountries` instead of `findAll`

Comment: using 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT fix the performance problem , https://forums.couchbase.com/t/spring-data-couchbase/8543  https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACOUCH-228

Comment: what is the difference between `@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter}")` and `findAll()` backed by a view ?